# Refer a Node in Forum Post

Tags: nodes

Is there a way to refer to a node in a forum post?

Like I want to put a hyperlink to the node with the node title as the display name. Is there any short handed variable that allows me to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Freelinking Casetracker](http://drupal.org/project/freelinking_casetracker).

Drupal.org itself also automatically converts [#nid] found in issue comments to Node links, but I'm not sure if they're using this module or another similar input filter.

Writing your own [input filter](http://www.lullabot.com/articles/drupal-input-formats-and-filters) is pretty straightforward if those don't exactly match your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Freelinking](https://www.drupal.org/project/freelinking) (you don't need the Freelinking Casetracking extension).

This project implements a filter framework for easier creation of HTML links to other pages on the site or to external sites.  To refer to a node with nid 42, you write `[[nid:42]]`.  This will produce a hyperlink to the node with the node title as the display name.